# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object' to type 'Microsoft.Expression.DesignModel.DocumentModel.DocumentNode'

Tags: wpf, exception, designer

I have a custom control I use that works correctly but throws an exception in the designer.

The exception message is "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object' to type 'Microsoft.Expression.DesignModel.DocumentModel.DocumentNode'"

The XAML is like this:

```
<custom:GaugeControl Value="{Binding Path=PaperRemaining}"
                     Stops="{StaticResource AutomationGaugeStops}"/>
```

The issue is with the `Stops="{StaticResource AutomationGaugeStops}"`; if I define the value in place (or remove that bit altogether) it does not complain.

The AutomationGaugeStops is defined in a separate file.

```
<GradientStopCollection x:Key="AutomationGaugeStops">
    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource AutomationIndicatorGreen}"
                  Offset="1.0" />
    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource AutomationIndicatorYellow}"
                  Offset="0.5" />
    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource AutomationIndicatorRed}"
                  Offset="0.0" />
</GradientStopCollection>
```

The Stops property is declared in the GuageControl codebehind.

```
 public GradientStopCollection Stops
    {
        get { return (GradientStopCollection)GetValue(StopsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StopsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StopsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Stops", typeof(GradientStopCollection), typeof(GaugeControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(new GradientStopCollection(
            new[]{
                new GradientStop(Colors.Green, 1.0),
                new GradientStop(Colors.Yellow, 0.5),
                new GradientStop(Colors.Red,0)
            }), StopsChanged));
```

This compiles and runs as expected but I'd love to understand and get rid of this error. Can anyone explain what is happening here?